# Finding n-tuple that minimizes expensive cost function

Tags: optimization, combinations, combinatorics

Suppose there are three variables that take on discrete integer values, say w1 = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12}, w2 = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12}, and w3 = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12}. The task is to pick one value from each set such that the resulting triplet minimizes some (black box, computationally expensive) cost function.

I've tried the surrogate optimization in Matlab but I'm not sure it is appropriate. I've also heard about simulated annealing but found no implementation applied to this instance.

Which algorithm, apart from exhaustive search, can solve this combinatorial optimization problem?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If nothing can be assumed about the cost, nothing clever can be done, the black box can mislead any trick that skips even a single combination. But you probably know *something* about the cost, right?

Comment: @harold Thanks for your reply. The cost is the root relative squared error found by cross-validating, in this particular case, a gaussian process regression model based on available data. I've tried but still haven't found any info from it (if there is any at all) that could be of use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The requirement/benefit of Simulated Annealing (SA), is that the objective surface is somewhat smooth, that is, we can be close to a solution.

- For a completely random spiky surface- you might as well do a random search
- If it is anything smooth, or even sometimes, it makes sense to try SA.

The idea is that (sometimes) changing only 1 of the 3 values, we have little effect on out blackbox function.

Here is a basic example to do this with Simulated Annealing, using [frigidum](https://pypi.org/project/frigidum/) in Python

```
import numpy as np

w1 = np.array( [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12] )
w2 = np.array( [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12] )
w3 = np.array( [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12] )

W = np.array([w1,w2,w3])

LENGTH = 12
```

I define a black-box using the [Rastrigin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rastrigin_function) function.

```
def rastrigin_function_n( x ):
    """
        N-dimensional Rastrigin
    
        https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rastrigin_function
        
        x_i is in [-5.12, 5.12]
    """
    A = 10
    n = x.shape[0]
    
    return A*n + np.sum( x**2- A*np.cos(2*np.pi * x) )
 
def black_box( x ):
    """
        Transform from domain [1,12] to [-5,5]
        to be able to push to rastrigin
    """
    x = (x - 6.5) * (5/5.5)
    
    return rastrigin_function_n(x)
```

Simulated Annealing needs to modify state X. Instead of taking/modifying values directly, we keep track of indices. This simplifies creating new proposals as an index is always an integer we can simply add/subtract 1 modulo LENGTH.

```
def random_start():
    """
        returns 3 random indices
    """
    return np.random.randint(0, LENGTH, size=3)

def random_small_step(x):
    """
        change only 1 index
    """
    d = np.array( [1,0,0] )
    if np.random.random() < .5:
        d = np.array( [-1,0,0] )
        
    np.random.shuffle(d)
    return (x+d) % LENGTH

def random_big_step(x):
    """
        change 2 indici
    """
    d = np.array( [1,-1,0] )        
    np.random.shuffle(d)
    
    return (x+d) % LENGTH

def obj(x):
    """
        We have a triplet of indici,
        
        1. Calculate corresponding values in W = [w1,w2,w3]
        2. Push the values in out black-box function
    """
    indices = x
    values = W[np.array([0,1,2]), indices]
    
    return black_box(values)
```

And throw a SA Scheme at it

```
import frigidum

local_opt = frigidum.sa(random_start=random_start, 
                        neighbours=[random_small_step, random_big_step], 
                        objective_function=obj, 
                        T_start=10**4, 
                        T_stop=0.000001, 
                        repeats=10**3, 
                        copy_state=frigidum.annealing.naked)
```

I am not sure what the minimum for this function should be, but it found a objective with `47.9095` with indicis `np.array([9, 2, 2])`

---

Edit:

- For frigidum to change the cooling schedule, use `alpha=.9`. My experience is that all the work of experiment which cooling scheme works best doesn't out-weight simply let it run a little longer. The multiplication you proposed, (sometimes called geometric) is the standard one, also implemented in frigidum. So to implement `Tn+1 = 0.9*Tn` you need a `alpha=.9`. Be aware this cooling step is done after N repeats, so if repeats=100, it will first do 100 proposals before lowering the temperature with factor `alpha`
- Simple variations on current state often works best. Since its best practice to set the initial temperature high enough to make most proposals (>90%) accepted, it doesn't matter the steps are small. But if you fear its soo small, try 2 or 3 variations. Frigidum accepts a list of proposal functions, and combinations can enforce each other.
- I have no experience with MINLP. But even if, so many times experiments can surprise us. So if time/cost is small to bring another competitor to the table, yes!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Indeed, the cost function can be considered smooth enough. So, as you mentioned, SA looks appropriate. The way you proposed new points can be generated was a very smart move. I believe I could go easy by changing one coordinate at a time, in an attempt to keep a small neighborhood. I think I could also consider a more conservative cooling schedule, say Tn+1 = 0.9*Tn, I'm not sure. One more thing, if it is not too much to ask: can a MINLP + branch and bound implementation do some good in this case? Anyway, I appreciated very much your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try every possible combination of the three values and see which has the lowest cost.

Comment: Yes, that's a solution. But imagine now we add three more variables. We'd have to process 12^6 possible combinations. Considering one evaluation of the cost function takes about 5s, it'd take around 4,147 hours of continuous computation.

Comment: If it has to be the minimum value for all variables and you know nothing about the function I think you have to try them all. How else can you know that you have the minimum value? You could run in parallel on many cores.